# Does anyone know about AppExchange App Analytics's Price?

Tags: appexchange, analytics, app

I currently consider use AppExchange App Analytics to analytics all my product. But I cannot found the price information about it, does anyone know about the detail? Where I can found such document?

Comment: If you are a partner, it is part of your partner bundle (I.e. no extra cost).

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Partners get app analytics as part of the partner benefits (so no extra cost). You do, however, need to raise a Partner Support case to have it enabled on your PBO/LMO as covered [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/appexchange-partner-intelligence-basics/get-started-with-partner-intelligence) - search for "log a case".